# Are iVar declarations inside a header file's @interface braces strong or weak in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is the following declaration and call a strong or weak reference? I know that a strong reference inside an NSNotificationCenter block can lead to a retain cycle, so I'm trying to avoid that.

Declaration:

```
@interface MPOCertifiedAccountsViewController : MPORootViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {

    UITableView *certifiedTableView;
}
```

Call:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:MPOFriendManagerManagerDidFinishRefreshingLocal
                                                          object:nil
                                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                      usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

                                                          [certifiedTableView reloadData];

                                                      }];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All instance variables are by default *strong*. However, that is not relevant here because

```
[certifiedTableView reloadData];
```

is in fact

```
[self->certifiedTableView reloadData];
```

and that retains `self`, not the instance variable. So you have a retain cycle here,
independent of whether `certifiedTableView` is a strong or weak instance variable.

You can solve that with the well-known technique of creating a weak reference to `self`:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

which is used in the block:

```
typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
if (strongSelf != nil) {
    [strongSelf->certifiedTableView reloadData];
}
```

You should also consider to use a *property* instead of an instance variable.
With `self.certifiedTableView` you see immediately that `self` is retained.

Comment: So can I fix this by using the code `__block typeof(self) blockSelf = self; [blockself->certifiedTableView reloadData];`

Comment: @MikeV: Assuming that you compile with ARC, you have to create a weak reference, not a __block.

Comment: Ok great. I'm a little confused as to what the differences between __block and __weak are, but I'll look more into that. Thanks

Comment: @MartinR -- I've been wondering whether the retain count gets incremented for self or the iVar in this case.  Are you *sure*?  (It is clear that self.property calls a getter on self, but _iVar is a naked pointer w/o self that *could* be retained w/o self if the compiler wanted, it seems to me)

Comment: That last edit fixed the compile error I was about to ask you about. I'll accept your answer when I can in 4 minutes. Thanks again!

Comment: @MikeV: In the ancient "Manual Reference Counting" times, __block was used to create a variable which is not retained in the block. This behaviour has changed with ARC and you have to use __weak now. This should be documented in the "Transition to ARC Release Notes".

Comment: @stevesliva: Yes, I am quite sure.